# Embedding a Web Browser/HTML Engine in Java

Tags: java, html, css, google-chrome, mozilla

I am making an application in java which would be showing a HTML web page, getting the address of the webpage from a config file. The web page will be on the local disk. Now what i want is, when i start the Java program, the program will be showing the the webpage fullscreen on the computer without the mouse cursor. Now for that i would be first needing a HTML Engine or a web browser which can run inside the java application(events liek press of button etc etc will be passed to the web page from the java application). I cant find a way to show these web pages. I would be needing to show current tech web pages , such that it can process everything from jQuery, Js, Ajax, CSS3, HTML 5. So that beautiful web pages are able to be shown through the Java program.

Comment: I would be open to using native access if i can get a good thing

Answer (score 2):

JxBrowser is a good api for such purpose. It uses the chromium engine which offers an optimum speed just like native browsers. I have used it and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can give a try to [jxbrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser)

It promise to be a very good component.

From the home page:

> Embed a lightweight Chromium-based Swing component into your Java
>   application to display modern web pages built with HTML5, CSS3,
>   JavaScript, Flash, Silverlight etc.

Comment: JxBrowser is free for open-source and academic projects: https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser#evaluate

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you're willing to use javaFx.

I'm not sure to which extent the latest html5 and css3 goodies are supported, but it's a decent browser enough : [java fx WebView component](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm)

Comment: Well, i actually want to use the available HTML 5 & CSS3, so that i can get a good powerful UI. I was thinking of setting up a UI under java but i figured if i use the current web techs, then it would be much better since it can already do so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the SWT Browser control if your application runs on Windows.
It wraps the currently installed Internet Explorer and gives you a very powerful access to its functionality including event listeners, etc.